# R generate random data from several distributions using kwargs

Tags: r, random, parameters

## Question:

I want to generate random sample from several distributions, e.g. `norm`, `pois` etc. However, I want to specify parameters to `rdist` function, like passing parameters to function call.

## Attempt:

I tried with something I did in python `partial` or `**kwargs`

```
dist = 'rnorm' # dist
n = 100 # sample size
para1 = c(0,1) # parameters
mean(get(dist)(n,para1)) # it fails

para2 = c(mean = 0, sd = 1)# parameters
mean(get(dist)(n,para2)) # it fails
```

Output:

> ```
> [1] 0.6318898
> [2] 0.4246129
> ```

As we can see from the output, `rnorm` did not produce samples from `norm(mean = 0,sd = 1)`,beacause sample mean is around 0.5. The output randoms are generated from `rnorm(1,mean = 0,sd = 1)` and `rnorm(1,mean = 1, sd =1)` one by one.

Comment: "rnorm did not produce samples from norm(mean = 0,sd = 1)" It didn't? How can you tell?

Comment: Outputs shows that it generate a sample with sample mean around 0.5. Actually, it generates a sample with `rnorm(n = 1,mean = 0,sd = 1)` , `rnorm(n = 1,mean = 1,sd = 1)` , `rnorm(n = 1,mean = 0,sd = 1)` etc. So the expectation mean of samples are 0.5 @HongOoi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `do.call` to call a function as a character name and pass function arguments in a list (see also `?do.call`):

```r
## sample from standard normal
(X <- do.call("rnorm", args = list(n = 10, mean = 0, sd = 1)))
#>  [1]  1.4127136 -0.4113396  1.7546034  0.6741983 -1.3499156 -0.8033819
#>  [7] -1.6393473 -0.7667389  0.7157213 -1.1061452

mean(X)
#> [1] -0.1519632
```

Comment: I figure this out too, I always get confused by `get`,`eval`,'parse' and 'do.call' T-T